# RecyclerView With Two Layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to put a Header TextView at the top of my RecyclerView so I have put two layouts inside my RecyclerView I have followed some tutorials and tried to modify the code up to here but I can't get it right

Under onCreateViewHolder it gives me a cannot resolve inflate(int) so how should I call it

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
public class TheSimsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int LAYOUT_ONE  = 0;
private static final int LAYOUT_TWO = 1;

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public TheSimsAdapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch ( viewType ) {

        case LAYOUT_ONE: return new ViewHolderFirst(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.top_textview));

        case LAYOUT_TWO: return new ViewHolderSecond(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item));
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {

        case LAYOUT_ONE:
            ViewHolderFirst viewHolderFirst = (ViewHolderFirst)holder;

            break;

        case LAYOUT_TWO:
            ViewHolderSecond viewHolderSecond = (ViewHolderSecond)holder;
            AdapterData data = mItems.get(position);
            viewHolderSecond.code.setText(data.getCode());
            viewHolderSecond.result.setText(data.getResult());

            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}



class ViewHolderFirst extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView header;

    public ViewHolderFirst(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        header = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_textview);

    }
}

class ViewHolderSecond extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView code;
    public TextView result;

    public ViewHolderSecond(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        code = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sims_code);
        result = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sims_result);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: "I can't get it right" -- please explain, in detail, what "I can't get it right" means.

Comment: under onCreateViewHolder it gives me a cannot resolve inflate(int) so how should I call it

Comment: and again .... 3 questions with the same problem ... position % 2 will cause that different layout will be appyled on odd/even rows ... not first/rest ...  also if header is not a part of mItems you should use position - 1 to get the right item then, logically, getItemCount should return count of mItems + 1 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.top_textview, parent, false)
```

in your createViewHolder-method.